# Implement curl request in R

Tags: r, curl, httr, rcurl

I am trying to access the Amadeus travel [API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/authorization-262)

To obtain a token, the given curl is:

```
curl "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}"
```

My RScript Attempt is:

```
library("httr")

# Get Token
response <- POST("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token",
                 add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
                 body = list(
                   "grant_type"     = "client_credentials",
                   "client_id"      = API_KEY,
                   "client_secret"  = API_SECRET),
                 encode = "json")
response
rsp_content <- content(response, as = "parsed", type = "application/json")
rsp_content
```

Resulting in the error:

```
Response [https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token]
  Date: 2021-07-23 00:59
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 217 B

        {
            "error":"invalid_request",
            "error_description": "Mandatory grant_type form parameter missing",
            "code": 38187,
            "title": "Invalid parameters"
        }
>
```

What is the correct way to call this API to obtain a token using R?

Comment: The `encode = "json"` doesn't seem correct. Try `encode="form"`

Comment: You are correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `curl -d` option is used to send data in the same way an HTML form would. To match that format, use `encode="form"` rather than `encode="json"` in the call to `POST()`.